# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool security related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1694).

Answer (score 20):

[image: Crypto Stackexchange]

Answer (score 19):

[image: OWASP - Application Security Is Not Just for Developers]

Answer (score 14):

[image: KeePass Password Storage]

Answer (score 14):

[image: The Quieter you become...]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Security B-Sides]

Answer (score -1):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: Martin - similar to my comment on cnst's post. Your image is at the wrong size - please edit to be 220x250. Thanks.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Nope. Please see [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1521) - it works on all other Metas. If you have further doubts, either discuss it with Kyle Cronin or take it to meta.sx.

Comment: Ahh - yours is slightly different to cnst's in that it is actively generated, which may explain why it may work. It certainly looks the wrong size here - twice as big as all the other pictures.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, I can assure you that's it's always "actively generated" to 440x500, not 220x250; also, for discussion sake, let me point out that it's not generated at "imgur", either, technically failing the *"Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)"* requirement, too.

Answer (score -3):

[image: @StackSecurity]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score -3):

[image: Do you have the right to keep and bear crypto? Find out on SE Law!]

Comment: Related meta post at http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/2097/16831

Answer (score -12):

[image: Simon Is Teh Donut]

Comment: No, please. Fun in the chatroom is fine but these ads will be seen by everyone on the Internet, not just by the dozen or so chatroom regulars who'll understand that.

Comment: @Gilles **A:** it'll only go up if it gets 6 upvotes (which it won't cause I'll delete it first) and **B:** I made an ad, now it's *your* turn to make a *better* one. GO! NO EXCUSES!

Comment: Lordy. **QUIT UPVOTING**. You're gonna make me have to delete it after only 2 days.

Comment: * sweet bagels!

Comment: HA! Props to you, sir.

Comment: @Gilles You're a donut.