# Is a Retina JPEG image of a CC-BY-2.0 bear's arms prohibited as a community ad on security?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bug

People seem to be downvoting the following ****bear's <strike>arms</strike> crypto**** community ad:

- https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2096/16831

---

Here's the ad, which is exactly 220x250, with Retina support:

- [image]

---

1. The primary reasons for downvotes given is that the image is 440x500 instead of 220x250, which it is not — it's just a Retina one instead.

   Is this really a problem?  Do the rules really meant to prohibit Retina support? Must one drop Retina?
2. A secondary reason given is that it's not "GIF or PNG" — it is JPEG instead.

   Is this really a problem?  Should one convert this photo to a GIF or PNG?
3. Additionally, someone managed to find a third reason — ad contains a CC-BY-2.0 image of a lovely bear with cute arms.  This someone claims that it cannot be used in the ad once shrank to 220x250 non-Retina pixels.

   But I disagree — it's used the same way on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear (and in Google, too), without any credits, unless you click on the image and perform extra steps.

   My understanding is that each ad has a link back to the voting page (if you hover over the ad once in circulation), thus that could remain to be the only place where the credits are given.  Is this line of thought incorrect?  Must a different image be found?

Comment: You seem to be involved in the Law community, how can you not understand that these are the rules that were defined to maintain a certain standard for ads? Without these specs, the ads system would become quite chaotic. Also, at this time, I see three downvotes on your submission and you seem to react as if the whole community has downvoted you. Finally, if you disagree with the rules, I suggest that you take it to meta.SE.

Comment: @Simon, the fact that I'm involved in the law community just means that I know what a precedent is; in fact, as has been mentioned elsewhere, Retina images are routinely appearing at various community ads throughout the network, as Martin Schröder mentions, [starting from as early as 2013](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1521).  I'm precisely involved in the law community to not have my actions directed by various misconceptions, and to learn and master concepts like the implicit "unless there's a good reason otherwise".

Answer (score 4):

The  specification is very... specific, and it is given in the post describing how to submit adverts.

- It must be 220x250 pixels - retina is not even vaguely relevant here. "With Retina support" does not make your image 220x250. It is 440x500. The image itself needs to be exactly the right size in pixels
- Yes, it must be a GIF or PNG

Those two aren't negotiable.

My understanding of your final point is a bit woollier,and I'm happy to defer to others who understand these kind of licences better than I:

- This image requires attribution, and this is not going to be readable when this image is resized, and as I understand it, crediting the original work may not be doable from the voting collection page - this will vary based on the licence a particular image is provided under.

Comment: What is the reason that it's so specific? Why does JPEG have to be excluded?  Wasn't it merely a suggestion that a text-only graphic not be made in JPEG, but if you have an image, that's ok?

Comment: It's the specific formats that the routine which displays these uses. I think your downvotes are mostly around the fact there is a very simple set of rules and your entry doesn't meet a couple of them - I think the licencing one is due to the fact attention has been raised on your post so folks are delving into it further.

Comment: Please discuss see [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1521), which is in use at most metas.